# OnHScroll or OnVScroll executing twice

Tags: c++, mfc, slider

I have an C++ MFC program and I'm trying to use a couple of horizontal sliders.

I already added `ON_WM_HSCROLL()` to my Message Map and I have this function to deal with changes in any slider:

```
void CAppDlg::OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{

    switch (pScrollBar->GetDlgCtrlID()) {
        case IDCAM1_ZOOMSLIDE:
            // do stuff
            return;
       case IDCAM2_ZOOMSLIDE:
            // do stuff
            return;
        default:
            return;
    }

    CDialog::OnHScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
}
```

I tried to put a breakpoint on the switch line and realized that every time I change the slider, OnHScroll() is executed 2 times.

**Why is that and how can I change this behavior?**

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you are getting SB_LEFT (or SB_RIGHT) and SB_ENDSCROLL messages.  Try looking at the value of nSBCode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Steve Wellens suggested,

I'm not using the `nSBCode`.

`OnHScroll` is being executed the first time with `nSBCode=SB_PAGELEFT` and a second time with `nSBCode=SB_ENDSCROLL`.

A simple `switch` or `if` is enough to deal with this.